# Analysis of XML structured data

Tags: c#, xml

My work uses software to fill out records that are expressed as XML documents. I have the task of trawling through these XML files to pull statistics out of them. The files themselves adhere to no schema and if a form field doesn't get filled out then the XML corresponding to that field is not created.

What's my best approach?

Example XML:

```
<Form>
    <Field>
        <id>Field ID</id>
        <value>Entered Value</value>
    </Field>
</Form>
```

I have been attempting to write software that I can use to query the files but have not been able to come up with anything even remotely useful.

Any thoughts appreciated.

EDIT: In terms of C#, what I would like (Though I'm sure it isn't possible) is a Dictionary that has a string as the key and the corresponding value could EITHER be a string or another Dictionary.

Comment: Scripting [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) might be a way to start.  Note that you'll have to have some description of the form (whether you have an existing description, or create one yourself) to be able to use the files at all, let alone automate pulling data from them.  If they're all different, then you'll simply need to browse them by hand.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Could you please be more specific about what kind of query you need to make? Do all your files look like the example you gave or are there other formats as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is like this ↓ ?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Form>
 <Field>
  <id>People1</id>
  <value>C Sharp</value>
 </Field>
 <Field>
  <id>People2</id>
  <value>C Sharp</value>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <id>People3</id>
   <value>C</value>
 </Field>
```

Source:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var result = from p in doc.Descendants("Form").Descendants("Field")
                     select new { ID = p.Element("id").Value, VALUE = p.Element("value").Value };

        foreach (var x in result)
            Console.WriteLine(x);

        var gr = from p in result
                 group p by p.VALUE into g
                 select new { Language=g.Key , Count=g.Count() };


        foreach (var x in gr)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Language:{0} Count:{1}" , x.Language , x.Count));

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too big, I would suggest `perl` and the [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) module. This will map the XML to a perl array of hashes, and then you can simply loop through it like normal. Something like:

```
my $xml = XML::Simple::XmlIn( 'file.xml', force_array => [ 'Form', 'Field' ] );
my %fld_counts;
foreach my $form ( @{$xml->{Form}} )
{
    # Any start record processing...
    foreach my $fld ( @{$form->{Field}} )
    {
        my $id = $fld->{id}
        my $val = $fld->{value}
        # Do something with id/value... like...
        $fld_counts{$id}++;
    }
}
```

So just adjust that structure based on the stats you want to gather

Answer (score 0):

For parsing XML I prefer using plain XmlReader. Granted, it's more verbose, but it's super efficient and transparent, at least for me. For example:

```
using(var xr = XmlReader.Create('your stream here'))
    while(xr.Read())
        if(xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            switch(xr.Name) {
                case "brands":
                    // do something here with this element,
                    // like possibly reading the whole subtree...
                    using(var xrr = xr.ReadSubtree())
                        while(xrr.Read()) {
                            // working here...
                        }
                    break;
                case "products":
                    // that is another element
                    break;
                case "some-other-element":
                    // and so on
                    break;
            } // switch
```